# Trying to solve problem related to continuous functions

Tags: functions, continuity, continued-fractions

A function $f$ is defined by
$$
\begin{equation}
f(x)= \begin{cases}   -2x^3-3 \text{ for } x < -1 \\      ax+b \text{ for } -1 \leq x < 1 \\      2x^2+1 \text{ for } 1 \leq x\\    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. The function $f$ is continuous. Find $a$ and $b$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). [PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq) (problem statement questions - where you just paste the problem and ask "what is the answer") do not belong on Math.SE. Consider adding context to the question such as what you've tried so far or what you're stuck on. Also, this looks like a homework problem - you should try to solve those yourself; we can help troubleshoot, but we won't do your work for you.

Comment: Hint: $\lim\limits_{x\to -1^-}f(x)=f(-1)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=f(1)$ gives you two conditions on $a,b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $−2x^3−3$ at $x=−1$ which must be equal to $ax+b$ at $x=−1$.

Similarly, compute $2x^2+1$ which must coincide with $ax+b$ at $x=1$.

From 1 and 2 cases we get $a-b=1$

From 2 and 3 cases we get $a+b=3$

Thus $2a=4$, hence $a=2$, therefore $b=1$

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: Use the fact that continuous univariate functions when graphed have no jumps. So compute $−2x^3−3$ at $x=-1$ which must be equal to $ax+b$ at $x=-1$. Similarly, $2x^2+1$ must coincide with $ax+b$ at $x=1$. Then you just have a system of equations of two variables.